# Rails PaperClip Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ~rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm getting this error in Unicorn.log when trying to attach files with paper clip on my ubuntu virtual server app:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 312ms (ActiveRecord: 10.1ms)

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ~rails):
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

In the controller I have

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :img,
    url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    validates_attachment_content_type :img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

If this info is not enough please comment where else the issue could reside, and I'll happily share more code.

Comment: I have a feeling that if you set your path as "~rails/umbertoputzu" that your app is unable to find the path. Try using ":rails_root", so that'll place you in the root of your app. So... ":rails_root/public..."

Comment: Tried it. No it's not that.

Comment: The solution was to give larger access to the rails files on my virtual server. I used $sudo chmod -R 755 and it was fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that the user that handles Rails on the virtual server didn't have all the access needed to generate files on behalf of paperclip in the app's folder. So I gave larger access to the folder using this terminal command:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 775 /RailsAppFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
path: "~rails/umbertoputzu/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
```

with

```
path: "~/rails/umbertoputzu/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
```